# A330 flown by low cost airline - is 8 cabin crew really all they have?

Tags: crew, flight-attendant, australia, airbus-a330, low-cost-carrier

I'm reading the [Australian Transport Safety Bureau report on an incident involving an AirAsia X A330](https://www.atsb.gov.au/media/5771380/ao-2015-029-final-report.pdf) (PDF). The flight in question was intended to be Sydney to Kuala Lumpur so something like a ten to twelve hour flight.

The report mentions that there were 8 cabin crew on board.

[Wikipedia says AirAsia has 377 seats in their A330's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirAsia_X#Fleet). Can it be true that they service that many seats with only 8 cabin crew ?

Comment: For what it's worth, [according to FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/XAX223/history/20160928/0055Z/YSSY/WMKK), that flight usually takes around 8.5 hours, not 10-12.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The number of flight attendants required on flights are mandated by international safety regulations. For planes with up to 19 passenger seats, no flight attendant is needed. For larger planes, one flight attendant per 50 passenger seats is needed.—[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_attendant#Overview)

Eight cabin crew is enough. 377/50 is 7.54.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the mandatory level was so few. I'm used to seeing what looks like 30 odd FA's getting off a bit jet but I guess a lot of that is higher FA:PAX ratio for business and 1st class neither of which AirAsia X have. On a long flight when some FA's might be resting it doesn't leave many people in the cabin if something bad happens.

Comment: @glaucon, that number is how many FAs must be on duty at any given time, but I believe that flight is just under the length where shifts would be needed.

Comment: @glaucon There aren't usually anywhere close to 30, but it is indeed usually more than 8 on the major airlines. It's also worth noting that AirAsia has only a very small (12 seats) business class and no first class. Usually the FA/passenger ratios are much higher in those classes than in economy on long-haul flights, but AirAsia probably only has 1 or 2 FAs normally working the business cabin.